# PHPUnit does not color output

Tags: phpunit

how can I enable a colored output for my tests?
I tried the command `phpunit --color=always file.php`, but it did not work!

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be `--colors` Not `--color` check the [docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html)

Comment: ./vendor/bin/phpunit --colors not working more. PHPUnit 7.1.5

Comment: If you want it always displays colors you have use the flag like so `--colors=always` otherwise it will be set to `auto` by default check the new [docs](http://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/textui.html)

Comment: thanks for reply. But I found what I needed: --testdox

Comment: @Maykonn First time to know about it, I checked it and it sounds cool.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't get color then you can override the phpunit.xml file on your main file.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
        colors="true">

</phpunit>`
```

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Windows command line does not natively support colors. Download Git for Windows, run 'phpunit' from the command line in the Bash shell, and you will get colors.